# What's the point on gettext syntax?

Tags: localization

So far I've been handling some translations in Wordpress and tried to read the official gettext documentation but won't get the point of one maybe simple thing: What's the differences between those startings like __(, _e(, etc.? And even more: which others are there beside? Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: Thank all of you for your elaborate answers! I really appreciate this here!

Comment: ...Maybe one further question to this: Can the entry of the text-domain be left out? I upright started bring it to every string I wanted to translate but then recognized some examples in the Wordpress codex which don't contain it at all...

Comment: ... Okay, now I came across it in this codex page - sorry for this redundant question :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`__` (double underscore) is the base translate function. It translates a string and returns it as a string.

`_e` does the same as `__`, but echo's the result immediately.

`_x` is the contextual translate function. It has a second option to provide context to people doing the translation.

`_ex` is the same as `_x`, but echo's the result.

Example of using `_x`:

```
$string = _x( 'Buffalo', 'an animal', 'plugin-domain' );
$string = _x( 'Buffalo', 'a city in New York', 'plugin-domain' );
$string = _x( 'Buffalo', 'a verb meaning to confuse somebody', 'plugin-domain' );
```

Sometimes the same string can be different in other languages. Providing context to the translators can help them pick the right words.

Shortcut functions:

- `esc_attr__` : Equivalent to `__` but also runs the result through `esc_attr`.
- `esc_html__` : Equivalent to `__` but also runs the result through `esc_html`.
- `esc_attr_e` : Equivalent to `_e` but also runs the result through `esc_attr`.
- `esc_html_e` : Equivalent to `_e` but also runs the result through `esc_html`.
- `esc_attr_x` : Equivalent to `_x` but also runs the result through `esc_attr`.
- `esc_html_x` : Equivalent to `_x` but also runs the result through `esc_html`.

`_n` is the pluralization handler. Example:

```
$string = sprintf( _n(
        'You have %d taco.', 
        'You have %d tacos.', 
        $number, 
        'plugin-domain'), 
    $number );
```

In that example, there's two ways to say the number of tacos, depending on if it's singular or not. The first use of $number tells the `_n` function which version to use. The second use of $number happens in the sprintf, to replace the %d with the actual number in the string.

There is no echo function equivalent for `_n`, but there is a function named `_nx`. It's a combination of `_n` and `_x`. Pluralization and context.

`_n_noop` is a special one. It's used for translating pluralized strings, but not actually performing the translation immediately. This is useful if you want to make the strings centralized but actually do the work elsewhere. The function that actually does the work elsewhere is `translate_nooped_plural`.

Example:

```
$holder = _n_noop('You have %d taco.', 'You have %d tacos.', 'plugin-domain');
// ... later ...
$string = sprintf( translate_nooped_plural( $holder, $count ), $count );
```

This isn't used much, but can be handy for organization. If you put all your strings in one file, for example, then reference them elsewhere, this wouldn't be possible with just `_n`, you need something like `_n_noop` to do that.

`_nx_noop` is the same as `_n_noop`, but also can take a context for the translators, same as `_x`.

Note that you can put the domain into either the noop function call, or into the translate_nooped_plural function call. Whichever makes more sense for your organization. If both have a domain, then the one passed to the noop call wins.

`number_format_i18n` is the equivalent to PHP's built-in [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), but it adds in the handling for things like decimals and so on, which are different in other locales.

`date_i18n` is the equivalent to PHP's built-in [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), with all the pertinent handling there as well. Month names, day names, etc.

Also, [never break the laws](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/). Just a reminder. :)

Comment: Wow, this is really a good explanation of it! Thank you very much for helping! Now I see clear.

Answer (score 7):

### __(), _e() and _x(), _ex()

[`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) and [`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) are essentially both a wrapper of [`translate()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/translate) (do not use directly) and almost the same.

The difference lies in that [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) returns the translated string and [`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) echoes it. Both need to be fed a string as a required parameter and usually, though optional, also a textdomain.

Analogously, there's [`_x()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x) and [`_ex()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_ex), which let you specify a context that can describe where the string appears. If your project includes more than a few tens of translatable strings, using context makes a lot of sense.

Also, note the existence of [`_n()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n) and [`_nx()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_nx) for plurals.

### Example of common usage

```
$output = '<label for="some_field">' .
        _x( 'Some Information.', 'Some Form Field', 'your-text-domain' ) .
    '</label>' .
    '<input type="text" name="some_field" value="" />' .
    '<p class="description">' .
        _x( 'Here you can enter some info.', 'Some Form Field', 'your-text-domain' ) .
    '</p>';

return $output;
```

### Parameters

```
__( $text, $domain )
_e( $text, $domain )
_x( $text, $context, $domain )
_ex( $text, $context, $domain )
_n( $single, $plural, $number $domain )
_nx( $single, $plural, $number, $context, $domain )
```

All parameters but `$number` are strings.
All but `$domain` are required.

### Further flexibility with variables and sprintf()

If your strings will contain variable numbers or words, use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php):

```
$stars = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rating', true );
$title = get_the_title( $post->ID );

$output = '<p>' .
        sprintf(
            _x(
                'The movie titled %2$s received a %1$d star rating.',
                'Movie Description',
                'your-text-domain'
            ),
            $stars,
            $title
        ) .
    '</p>';

return $output;
```

### Additional resources

Some additional resources for the upcoming WordPress I18n Ninja:

- [Translating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)
- [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)
- [Localization function reference overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/#Miscellaneous_Functions)
- [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) (fantastic plugin!)
- [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)

Comment: Also check out ["Localization" under "Miscellaneous" in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/#Miscellaneous_Functions) for a complete breakdown of functions & detailed explanations.

Comment: & this is the place [where wp-polyglots meet](http://wppolyglots.wordpress.com/).

Comment: @Johannes Pille: I didn't notice your answer until I'd posted mine, should I delete my post?

Comment: @JeremyJared No, why? Further info can't be a bad thing, can it?! I think your answer is well thought through. +1 from me.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Edited into "additional resources".

Comment: Hopefully they will add `_en($text,$domain)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on translations, but the WordPress Codex Page has good documentation and explains the reason to use each instance.

**From the codex pages:**

`__()`

Is used when the message is passed as an argument to another function; `_e()` is used to write the message directly to the page. More detail on these two functions:

`__('message')`

Searches the localization module for the translation of 'message', and passes the translation to the PHP return statement. If no translation is found for 'message', it just returns 'message'.

`_e('message')`

Searches the localization module for the translation of 'message', and passes the translation to the PHP echo statement. If no translation is found for 'message', it just echoes 'message'.

*Note that if you are internationalizing a Theme or Plugin, you should use a* `"Text Domain"`.

The gettext framework takes care of most of WordPress. However, there are a few places in the WordPress distribution where gettext cannot be used:

- The main WordPress README file -- it's a static HTML file, not a PHP file, so it cannot be run through the gettext functions.
- A few error messages are generated very early in the WordPress loading cycle, before gettext is loaded.

[Link to the Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)

[Additional info regarding when gettext doesn't work](http://codex.wordpress.org/Files_For_Direct_Translation)

Hopefully that answers your question, if not let us know and maybe someone else can help or I can do some more research.