# What is meant by __('page','twentytwelve')

Tags: themes, localization, theme-twenty-twelve

I'm using twentytwelve theme with 1.0 version. I saw many codes like following,

```
'name' = __('page','twentytwelve');
```

If I give,

```
'name' = 'page';
```

It's also working fine. Then why using `__()`?
What is use of that?

Comment: I would venture to guess that you've either seen `array( 'name' => __('page','twentytwelve') );` or `$name = __('page','twentytwelve');`. Just as an aside.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Internationalization and localization (commonly abbreviated as i18n
>   and l10n respectively) are terms used to describe the effort to make
>   WordPress (and other such projects) available in languages other than
>   English, for people from different locales, who use different dialects
>   and local preferences.

[`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) is used when the message is passed as an argument to another function. [`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) is used to write the message directly to the page. More detail on this @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Comment: +1 and for a thorough breakdown on gettext in WP see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57735/whats-the-point-on-gettext-syntax/57748#57748)