# Custom menus created but does not show up in admin panel

Tags: menus

I am developing a theme of my own. In  `functions.php` I added -

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' ); 

function register_my_menus() { register_nav_menus( array(

         'front_login_menu' => _( 'front_login_menu location'),
         'top_front_general_menu' => _( 'top_front_general_menu'),
         'top_general_menu' => _( 'top_general_menu'),
         'top_student_menu' => _( 'top_student_menu'),
         'top_admin_menu' => _( 'top_admin_menu'), 
         'top_trainer_menu' => _( 'top_trainer_menu' ) ) ); }
```

Then I created the custom menus in the admin panel. But suddenly I found that those menus except one are not visible in the right side of the `Appearance -> Menus` page in online server but the theme locations do exist. But those menus are visible in my localhost. I was supposed to create them (some if not all) in online server too.

If I want to create one of those missing menus then the message says:

> ***The menu name .... conflicts with another menu name. Please try another.***

How can I get those menu names appear in the right side of the theme locations?

Comment: Try a very basic check, copy the menu name and in your editor try to find (typically Ctrl + F) the same keyword exist somewhere else. If so, dissolve the conflict. For function name try something different than `register_my_menus`. And moreover try debugging turned on into your WP installation.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam, I changed all the menu names and theme locations. The problem is when I create a menu after another one the previous menu disappears so I cannot add any menu item to the previous one. How to get rid of this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to initiate the menus again where [`register_nav_menus()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/register_nav_menu) itself is an initiator.

> **Syntax:** `<?php register_nav_menu( 'your-menu-handle', 'Your Menu Label' ); ?>`

Copy the following code and Paste them into your `functions.php` ***without*** any function or `add_action()`, I hope it'll work:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
     'front_login_menu' => __( 'Front Login Menu location'),
     'top_front_general_menu' => __( 'Top Front General Menu'),
     'top_general_menu' => __( 'Top General Menu'),
     'top_student_menu' => __( 'Top Student Menu'),
     'top_admin_menu' => __( 'Top Admin Menu'), 
     'top_trainer_menu' => __( 'Top Trainer Menu' )
    )
);
```

Use the following code into your theme, where you want to show the menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu (
            array (
                'theme_location'=>'front_login_menu', //change the slug here where necessary
                'fallback_cb'=>''
            )
        ); ?>
```

Comment: did not solve the question. The online server has prob in its  mysql DB. Thinking whether it is related with that,

Comment: How the menu codes are connected with your db prob - I'm thinking of that too. Ok, I did a minor edit with a double underscore (`__()`) instead of single underscore (`_()`). (*[know why](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116609/what-is-meant-by-page-twentytwelve)*)

Comment: When the `Browse` tab of the Db table was clicked, it showed error.  This problem was solved and the menu names also appeared in place.