# How can i create a tag with the template's name like below, and what is the purpose of using them?

Tags: theme-development

I saw these in a lot of WordPress themes, what are they used for and how can I create my own?
I mean for example the "twentythirteen" tag at the end, what contains the actual theme's name.

```
get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'twentythirteen'
edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is broken but what you are looking at-- that "twentythirteen"-- is a "text domain" which is used for theme translation. The text domain is a kind of "Key" for locating the right translation data. That is, the first part, 'Edit' for example, will be translated based on the "twentythirteen" translation strings.

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: Already answered [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116609/what-is-meant-by-page-twentytwelve).